# Jquery SlideShow with Image Transition

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow

Im looking for a image slideshow that uses jquery, similar to http://sliderjs.org/ the demo there. But instead of circles the ability to use my own image (which will be a horse). Are there any known jquery sliders which allow me to do this ?

Comment: please define **vector image** you can only use flat images on web or html5 canvas as i know

Comment: Well ofcourse the image will be a .png or .jpg or whatever is needed for the slider :)

Comment: not sure what you need not from that plugin, if you are searching for a similar plugin try googling for **Nivo Slider**

Comment: I voted +1 for mentioning your image will be a horse...